# How to get actual color value of text view in espresso

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I am trying to verify color of text view in android app.

healthHistoryPage.allergies.check(matches(hasTextColor(android.R.color.black))))

I am getting an error saying:

android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'has color with ID 17170444' doesn't match the selected view.

Expected: has color with ID android:color/black

But I dont see the whats the actual color value anywhere in error message. Is there a way I can fetch the actual color value if I dont have access to source code.

Comment: You just want to output the color code in error message? Then you could write your matcher (copy from hasTextColor and adjust error msg part)

Comment: Yes, I want to see the color code in error message. To be more precise, I am checking if the color is black. but actual color is Red. then I want to see in my error message that actual color is red and expected color is black. so test failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here the adjusted hasTextColor matcher of the original: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.java

```
public static Matcher<View> hasTextColor(final int colorResId) {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, TextView>(TextView.class) {
        private Context context;

        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(TextView textView) {
            context = textView.getContext();
            int textViewColor = textView.getCurrentTextColor();
            int expectedColor;

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 22) {
                expectedColor = context.getResources().getColor(colorResId);
            } else {
                expectedColor = context.getColor(colorResId);
            }

            return textViewColor == expectedColor;
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            String colorId = String.valueOf(colorResId);
            String colorCode = "";
            if (context != null) {
                colorId = context.getResources().getResourceName(colorResId);

                //added get color hex code
                @ColorInt int colorInt = context.getResources().getColor(colorResId);
                colorCode = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & colorInt));
            }
            description.appendText("has color with ID " + colorId);

            //added output color code in error msg
            description.appendText(" and color code: " +
                    colorCode);
        }
    };
}
```

Note: the `//added` comments with the modifications for the color hex code

This will log an error similar to:

> ... 
>   Expected: has color with ID com.appham.sandbox:color/colorAccent and
>   color code: #FF4081
>   ...